# Debian se reinicia solo

Tags: linux, login, debian

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con debian se me está reiniciando el sistema y me hace perder mis adelantos, estoy simulándolo con  virtualbox pero eso es lo único que me falta por solucionar el reinicio automático del sistema

[image: Debian[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5MTn.jpg)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: login]

Comment: publica tu /var/log/messages luego de que la maquina se ha reiniciado

Comment: o intenta con ```last reboot | less```

Comment: Revisa cómo tienes configurada la partición de **swap**, si está virtualizado podrías tener un problema de disco duro también.